# Xamarin/Maui Android, Task.Delay().ContinueWith, DisplayAlert not fired

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I have this code, but Display alert never fired, can't understand - why so?

```
await Task.Delay(_doublePressTimeout - _buttonReleaseTimeout)
    .ContinueWith(async c =>
    {
        if (pushed != Constants.Direction.Empty)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("qwe", pushed.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    });
```

But works this way:

```
await Task.Delay(_doublePressTimeout - _buttonReleaseTimeout);
if (pushed != Constants.Direction.Empty)
{
    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("qwe", pushed.ToString() + " begin", "OK");
}
```

**WHY?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks have an implicit `.ConfigureAwait(true)` when they're awaited straight up, which is why you have a warning to state it explicitly (or even better, use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` selectively for large performance increases where applicable).

`.ContinueWith` can also capture the context and/or schedule the continuation on specific threads, which you should be doing for UI access, but you need to call the overload with the parameters for it.

That said, you'll be hard pressed to find a valid use case for `.ContinueWith` over just task awaiting. As you can see from your own example, it's easy to translate broken `.ContinueWith` to correct (and simpler) `await Task` code.

Comment: So i just delaying task without ContinueWith?

Comment: Also, no matter what `pushed` is, I find it a large red flag to see things like `pushed.ToString() + " begin"` because it implies that the writer doesn't understand strings in C#. `pushed + " begin"` is much cleaner, and `$"{pushed} begin"` even much more so.

Comment: @MarkGrindcore I'm not sure exactly what you're asking (I read it as "so I'm just delaying the task without `ContinueWith`?" which obviously makes no sense), but if you're asking if you should avoid `ContinueWith` then absolutely yes, avoid it!

Comment: It just test case for myself, i would say just fast code for checking

Comment: `$"{pushed} begin"` is much faster to type, that's a systemic problem that your reflex is to call `ToString` which is what the red flag is for.